# What should I learn if I want to suggest photo editor settings in a photo service based on the users previous behaviour?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

I am not sure if this is the right place for a question like this, so please point me to some other forum if there is a better suited one.

I am building a photo organization application. I would like the app to give suggestions of what photos to keep and also what modifications to make to them, all based on previous choices made by that very same user.

So if the user uploads some photos (lets say 100) photos and deletes some of them that they dont like, and uses an editing function to modify the rest of them (like cropping, light adjustmenst, filters etc). All functions are available to the user in a web application. When the user uploads the next 100 photos I want to present suggestions of the same kind. Like "based of previous behaviour, you probably want to delete these photos and you most likely want to edit the other photos in this way". I guess I need some kind of specific model for each user that will learn what type of photos they like by feeding it data about what modification they have made to them.

I am not sure where to start. What should I learn ? Deep learning? Linear-regression? Computer Vision? Neural Networks? OpenAI? I have no idea. I started some course on Udemy but I quickly felt that I wasnt sure if I was even on the right track. I cant really google it as I dont know what topics to search for.

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: That said, I strongly recommend that you take in intro course on Machine Learning; this will give you an introduction to the various aspects of the field, what sorts of problems you can solve with various algorithms, and some work on identifying paradigms.  There are plenty of such classes.  For instance, just watching the videos from the Stanford course (key on instructor Andrew Ng) will likely give you enough vocabulary and pointers to start.

Comment: ... and your *next* question on the topic will be something we'll all want to answer ...

Comment: FYI, I suspect that this will turn out to be a job for SVM classification.